# assistance required in StringTokenizer in java

Tags: java

In the following code when i enter the line like = 1 2 3 
i want to produce the product of those numbers which will be = 6.. IT will have to produce dynamically .. such as if entered any times e.g, 1 2 3 4 5...

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        int number = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());


        list.push(number);


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            Integer a[] = new Integer[list.size()];
                a[i]=list.pop();




        }
```

Comment: What is the problem here ? I dont think the code that you pasted is complete. Please provide complete code and error if you are facing any ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misplaced the closing brace: the second loop should be after the first loop, not inside it.

Moreover, converting a list to an array can be done with `toArray` method instead of the loop.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    list.push(number);
}
/* Removed:
Integer a[] = new Integer[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        a[i]=list.pop();
}
*/
Integer a[] = list.toArray();
```